# *ngFor generated list of divs: first element occasionally changes its id from 1 to "2 or "3"

Tags: angular, object, instance, ngfor

I have this component:

```
<div class="list-item-container" *ngFor="let Group of groups; let i=index;">
    <app-groups-list-entry *ngIf="groups.length > 0" [group]="groups[i]"></app-groups-list-entry>   
</div>
```

As you see I pass to the child component a "group" object of type Group taken from an array; the object has an "id" field of type Number.

My list of divs is correctly created, in fact I get the following result (taken from browser inspector):

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Famiglia",
    "pic": "https://picsum.photos/100/100",
    "members": [
      1,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ],
    "admin": 1,
    "minApprove": 2,
    "movies": true,
    "shows": false,
    "genres": [
      18,
      36
    ],
    "matches": [
      205,
      63174
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bestie",
    "pic": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image",
    "members": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "admin": 1,
    "minApprove": 2,
    "movies": true,
    "shows": true,
    "genres": [
      18,
      10749
    ],
    "matches": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gnari",
    "pic": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529333166437-7750a6dd5a70?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fGZyaWVuZHN8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80",
    "members": [
      1,
      6,
      7,
      8
    ],
    "admin": 7,
    "minApprove": 3,
    "movies": false,
    "shows": true,
    "genres": [
      10765,
      80
    ],
    "matches": [
      63174
    ]
  }
]
```

However, after clicking back and forth from one to another it suddenly changes the "id" of the first item to equal the string "2" or "3" (see 4th row):

[image: id chs]

I realize the question is a little vague, but I really can't wrap my head around where and why it is triggering the change, so I was hoping to get some suggestions to get me going in the right direction.
The switch from number to string is particularly puzzling, and I think it could indicate where the problem is. I can provide more details and more code of course.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the app-groups-list-entry component doing with the groups. Is it possibly mutating them? You may also need to use a trackBy here to ensure ordering (not sure).

Comment: Nope, only [accessing their fields](https://i.imgur.com/BY4utJ1.png) to display them on the page.

I didn't know about trackBy, I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

From the symantics of your code, you may have better luck doing this.

```
<div class="list-item-container" *ngFor="let group of groups;">
    <app-groups-list-entry [group]="group"></app-groups-list-entry>   
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still happens.
The code is cleaner though, so thank you anyways!